# How do I zip files in Bazel?

Tags: zip, bazel

I have a set of files as part of the my repository. How do I produce a zip file out of those files in Bazel? I found a rules for `tar.gz` etc. but cannot find a way how to achieve a zip archive.

Found references mentioning zipper but couldn't figure out how to load it and use it. Can someone more experienced with Bazel help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The zipper utility is at `@bazel_tools//tools/zip:zipper`, this is its usage:

```
Usage: zipper [vxc[fC]] x.zip [-d exdir] [[zip_path1=]file1 ... [zip_pathn=]filen]
  v verbose - list all file in x.zip
  x extract - extract files in x.zip to current directory, or
       an optional directory relative to the current directory
       specified through -d option
  c create  - add files to x.zip
  f flatten - flatten files to use with create or extract operation
  C compress - compress files when using the create operation
x and c cannot be used in the same command-line.

For every file, a path in the zip can be specified. Examples:
  zipper c x.zip a/b/__init__.py= # Add an empty file at a/b/__init__.py
  zipper c x.zip a/b/main.py=foo/bar/bin.py # Add file foo/bar/bin.py at a/b/main.py

If the zip path is not specified, it is assumed to be the file path.
```

So it can be used in a `genrule` like this:

```
$ tree
.
├── BUILD
├── dir
│   ├── a
│   ├── b
│   └── c
└── WORKSPACE

1 directory, 5 files


$ cat BUILD
genrule(
  name = "gen_zip",
  srcs = glob(["dir/*"]),
  tools = ["@bazel_tools//tools/zip:zipper"],
  outs = ["files.zip"],
  cmd = "$(location @bazel_tools//tools/zip:zipper) c $@ $(SRCS)",
)


$ bazel build :files.zip
INFO: Analyzed target //:files.zip (7 packages loaded, 41 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:files.zip up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/files.zip
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.653s, Critical Path: 0.08s
INFO: 1 process: 1 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions


$ unzip -l bazel-bin/files.zip
Archive:  bazel-bin/files.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2010-01-01 00:00   dir/a
        0  2010-01-01 00:00   dir/b
        0  2010-01-01 00:00   dir/c
---------                     -------
        0                     3 files
```

It can similarly be used in Starlark:

```
def _some_rule_impl(ctx):

  zipper_inputs = []
  zipper_args = ctx.actions.args()
  zipper_args.add("c", ctx.outputs.zip.path)
  ....
  ctx.actions.run(
    inputs = zipper_inputs,
    outputs = [ctx.outputs.zip],
    executable = ctx.executable._zipper,
    arguments = [zipper_args],
    progress_message = "Creating zip...",
    mnemonic = "zipper",
  )


some_rule = rule(
  implementation = _some_rule_impl,
  attrs = {
    "deps": attr.label_list(),
    "$zipper": attr.label(default = Label("@bazel_tools//tools/zip:zipper"), cfg = "host", executable=True),
  },
  outputs = {"zip": "%{name}.zip"},
)
```

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. As far as I understand the zip contain file with absoluth path or just filename when flatten. Is it possible to output to specific folder in zip file? e.g. have file structure /dir/subdir/a and want a zip contain subdir/a?

Comment: yeah, the zipper tool supports this syntax: `[[zip_path1=]file1 ... [zip_pathn=]filen]`, so you can do `subdir/a=/dir/subdir/a`

Comment: I am struggling to make it work. How to work with lists and generate that mapping. Do I need to do it in Starlark? I was trying to use separate genrule to create structure I need (path) but obviously it preserves absolute paths

Comment: It depends on what your requirements are. You can use a genrule to generate the structure, but note that Starlark itself can't read the output of the commands run within the genrule (by design, Starlark is evaluated before any action is run). The actions that are registered from Starlark can read the output of the actions in the genrule. It might be helpful to post what you have so far to bazel-discuss@googlegroups.com

Comment: @ahumesky this doesn't seem to be working any more, or am I missing something.

Comment: @Rushipatel this seems to be working for me with bazel 2.0.0. what problem are you having?

Comment: @jaksky you can generate that mapping in a genrule, though if you need to process file path, you may need to do it in a macro or in starlark. just depends on what you need to do

Comment: @ahumesky This causes an issue when the number of source files to zip are large (Argument list too long). Is there a way to add to an existing zip in chunks within a rule implementation?

Comment: @yoonjesung although it doesn't show up in the usage help text, `zipper` appears to support options files using `@filename`: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/19532fbd3ae369d756ec8aa37a74a2c453a4cce9/third_party/ijar/zip_main.cc#L435

Answer (score 10):

A basic `pkg_zip` rule was added to [`rules_pkg`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_pkg/) recently. Here is a basic usage example from the unit tests:

```py
load("@rules_pkg//:pkg.bzl", "pkg_zip")

pkg_zip(
    name = "test_zip_basic",
    srcs = [
        "testdata/hello.txt",
        "testdata/loremipsum.txt",
    ],
)
```

---

You can specify the paths using the extra rules in `mappings.bzl`. Here is the [example](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_pkg/blob/9126ba807416c76c16054fd5b7b35dbf348ecf11/examples/rich_structure/BUILD) given by the Bazel team:

```py
load("@rules_pkg//:mappings.bzl", "pkg_attributes", "pkg_filegroup", "pkg_files", "pkg_mkdirs", "strip_prefix")
load("@rules_pkg//:pkg.bzl", "pkg_tar", "pkg_zip")

# This is the top level BUILD for a hypothetical project Foo.  It has a client,
# a server, docs, and runtime directories needed by the server.
# We want to ship it for Linux, macOS, and Windows.
#
# This example shows various techniques for specifying how your source tree
# transforms into the installation tree. As such, it favors using a lot of
# distict features, at the expense of uniformity.

pkg_files(
    name = "share_doc",
    srcs = [
        "//docs",
    ],
    # Required, but why?: see #354
    strip_prefix = strip_prefix.from_pkg(),
    # Where it should be in the final package
    prefix = "usr/share/doc/foo",
)

pkg_filegroup(
    name = "manpages",
    srcs = [
        "//src/client:manpages",
        "//src/server:manpages",
    ],
    prefix = "/usr/share",
)


pkg_tar(
    name = "foo_tar",
    srcs = [
        "README.txt",
        ":manpages",
        ":share_doc",
        "//resources/l10n:all",
        "//src/client:arch",
        "//src/server:arch",
    ],
)

pkg_zip(
    name = "foo_zip",
    srcs = [
        "README.txt",
        ":manpages",
        ":share_doc",
        "//resources/l10n:all",
        "//src/client:arch",
        "//src/server:arch",
    ],
)
```

Comment: any idea on how could you maintain paths of directories when creating zip using this rule

Comment: I was also wondering the same thing @Rushipatel. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Is it possible to specify the output name independently of the "name" attribute?