# Bazel rule to produce an AWS lambda bundle

Tags: aws-lambda, bazel

Suppose I have a simple lambda like:

`lambda/index.js`:

```js
exports.handler = (event, context) => {
  context.succeed('Hello, world. ');
};
```

I can create a (non-deterministic) zip like this:

```sh
(cd ./lambda && zip ../lambda.zip index.js)
```

How can I define a Bazel rule that creates an `.zip` file crafted to work with AWS Lambda?

The zip should look like this:

```sh
$ unzip -l ./lambda.zip

Archive:  ./lambda.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
       85  2021-03-18 19:18   index.js
---------                     -------
       85                     1 file
```

This is the simple case.

My second question is: suppose I have a more complex library that is built by Bazel, including run-time data etc, how do I bundle all of *that* into an AWS lambda bundle?

Answer (score 0):

Use pkg_zip: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57998883/4638604. If it were not available, then you can use [genrule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#genrule) to run any system command (like `zip`)