# Bazel convert tar to zip

Tags: bazel

Is there a way to convert a `tar` target (created using `rules_pkg`) and turn it into a `zip` target in Bazel?

```py
pkg_tar(
  name = "bundle-tar",
  srcs = [
    ":aws-lambda",
  ],
  include_runfiles = True,
  package_dir = "/",
)

pkg_zip(
  name = "bundle-zip",
  srcs = [
    ":bundle-tar", # ???
  ],
)
```

I imagine this could be accomplished using `@bazel_tools//tools/zip:zipper`?

---

This *kind of* works, but it is not deterministic:

```py
genrule(
  name = "bundle-zip",
  srcs = [ ':bundle-tar' ],
  outs = [ "bundle.zip" ],
  cmd = " && ".join([
    "tar xf $(location :bundle-tar)",
    "zip $@ $$(tar tf $(location :bundle-tar))",
  ]),
)
```

---

```py
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
  name = "rules_pkg",
  urls = [
    "https://mirror.bazel.build/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_pkg/releases/download/0.7.0/rules_pkg-0.7.0.tar.gz",
    "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_pkg/releases/download/0.7.0/rules_pkg-0.7.0.tar.gz",
  ],
  sha256 = "8a298e832762eda1830597d64fe7db58178aa84cd5926d76d5b744d6558941c2",
)

load("@rules_pkg//:deps.bzl", "rules_pkg_dependencies")

rules_pkg_dependencies()
```

Comment: Does https://github.com/zaucy/rules_7zip work for you?

Comment: Does having a `pkg_zip(name = "bundle-zip", srcs = [":aws-lambda"])` work? i.e. same sources as the tar, but `pkg_zip` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57914937/how-do-i-zip-files-in-bazel)  for a detailed explanation on how to convert tar to zip files. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).